# Axios doesn't set cookies from headers response, but fetch works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch, fastapi

I'm trying to set three cookies: access_token, refresh_token and logged_in from server side. I deployed FastAPI backend on heroku and react.js frontend on netlify. Of course, I set correctly cookies parameters with CORS policy on backend side. In localhost everything was fine, but after deploy frontend doesn't set cookies from axios request(withCredentials value is true). I don't see any cookies in Chrome application/Cookies and Firefox.

Early, I though that problem is on backend side, but when I used fetch request with credentials - everything was fine. Somebody has idea how to fix this problem?

my response cookies in FastAPI app

```
 response.set_cookie('access_token', access_token, ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN * 60,
                        ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN * 60, '/', None, True, True, samesite='none')
    response.set_cookie('refresh_token', refresh_token,
                        REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN * 60, REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN * 60, '/', None, True, True, 'none')
    response.set_cookie('logged_in', 'True', ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN * 60,
                        ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN * 60, '/', None, True,True, 'none')
```

my example requests in react app

```
const axi = async () => {
    await axios({
    url: 'https://example.com/auth/login',
    method: "post",  
    data: {"email": "exam@ple.eu", "password": "stringst"},
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
}

const fet = async () => {
    await fetch('https://example.com/auth/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      // mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include',
      body: {"email": "exam@ple.eu", "password": "stringst"},
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }
    }).then(res => {
       console.log(res)
    })
  }
```

Comment: No. I did this things for my backend. Status of 'auth/login' is 200. I bought ssl on heroku to make https on backend server, too. Fetch request set credentials, but axios doesn't.